# clicking on the image should display it inside the bootstrap body in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

HTML CODE:

```
   <div>

  <a  href="">
  <img src="haghwaylitecontroller.jpg" alt="gemcamera" style="width:150px" class="upload1">

  </a>
  <a href="">
  <img src="lightningswitchmodule.jpg" alt="gemcamera" 
  style="width:150px" class="upload1">
  </a>
  <a href="#" >
  <img src="videodoorphone.jpg" alt="gemcamera" style="width:150px" 
   class="upload1">
  </a>
 </div>
```

This is my html code. Here it is viewed as thumbnails .Onclicking this image the respective image should view up on the bootstrap panel body.

Bootstrap modal body:

```
  <div class="modal-body" id="modal-content">
    <div class = "row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">

    <div class = "col-sm-6" align="center">
    <div class="upload">
    <a href = "#" class = "thumbnail">
      <img src="{{asset('4008-cam/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-
      76x76@3x.png')}}" width="150" height="150">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
      onclick="window.location='';" align="center"><span 
          class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span>Upload 
    photo</button>
    </a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

SCRIPT CODE:`

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".upload1", function() {
    $(".upload").append('<img src="
    {{asset('**haghwaylitecontroller.jpg**')}}">');
    });
    });
    </script>
```

This is my script code.Here it should display the respective image which is clicked.By giving the specific names of the images it is working.But what I need is, the respective images should displayed on the modal body.
`

Comment: so the problem is that the modal does not show up or the image is displayed in the wrong place in the modal?

Comment: It showsup.But its not displaying the respective images

Comment: Also the image displaying in the wrong place

Comment: <a href = "#" class = "thumbnail">
      <img src="**{{asset('4008-cam/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-
      76x76@3x.png')}}**" width="150" height="150">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
      onclick="window.location='';" align="center"><span 
          class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span>Upload 
    photo</button>
    </a>-->the marked place is where the respective image should show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.imgimg').on('click', function () {

    var imageSRC = $(this).attr('src');
  console.log(imageSRC)
    //$('#MyModal').on('show.bs.modal', function  () {
     $(".someClass").attr("src", imageSRC);
      console.log("asddasasdasd")
//  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<img src="https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/maxresdefault.jpg" class="imgimg" width="500" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >


<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg" class="imgimg" width="500" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">


              <img class="someClass" src="" width="150" height="150">

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

ok first you grab the `src` of the clicked image by

```
$('.imgimg').on('click', function () {

    var imageSRC = $(this).attr('src');
```

Note that `imgimg` is a class that every picture that should be displayed in the modal should have. Now pass that argument in the modal like:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
 $(".someClass").attr("src", imageSRC);
 ....
```

The modal should look like this:

```
<div class="modal fade">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">


              <img class="someClass" src="" width="150" height="150">

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: where is that **myModal** is used

Comment: @nishanthi Check that codepen its working. Have multiple images can click on each of them and it shows them in the modal :)

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".upload1", function() {
   
     alert(imageSRC);
      $(".someClass").attr("src", imageSRC);
});
});
</script>

Comment: if its working on SO and on Codepen it should also work on your computer. You need to find the bug in your code, but the technique I gave you is right.

Comment: Here the image is already in the modal. On clicking with that image,the same image should display in the corresponding modal body position

Comment: I don't get what you want. You asked how to display the img in the modal and I showed it to you. "the image is in the modal" , "same image should display in the corresponding modal " you want to have two modals?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6Ld4ECMaY-eOUR3Y3dLVXV5blU/view-->this is what I required

Comment: "file can't be opened". I just leave it here. I always spend hours trying to figure out what you people want and in the end you don't even accept the answer/upvote. Good luck with your project I hope my answer helped you a bit to get closer to your goal.

Comment: I think the latest link will open. Yes your code helps me a lot!! Thankyou so much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149885/discussion-between-nishanthi-and-hansthefranz).

Comment: no lets not do that. As I said I will spend hours and in the end you won't even accept/upvote. At least you said "thank you" but please figure it out by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

By using your code,

**JUST REPLACE YOUR** `.upload` to `.modal-body`

```
`  $(".modal-body").append('<img src="
    {{asset('**haghwaylitecontroller.jpg**')}}">');`
```

**Check it!**

Comment: Sorry,I need to change the image when the clicks on the image